# Angular HTML string - rename attributes

Tags: html, angular, sanitization

I have a HTML string like

```
 <span class="diff-html-changed" id="1" changes="MyText" >test </span>
```

and I want to display the text as html. I include it like

```
displayedContentInTemplate: SafeHtml;
private sanitized: DomSanitizer,
....
displayedContentInTemplate = this.sanitized.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(contentAsString);
```

My problem is that the content of `changes` is not displayed. Therefore I thought to rename `changes` into `title`. This would display `MyText` when hovering the text.

How to change the attribute `changes` properly? A simple replace within the string might replace text which will belongs to the displayed text. And with simple creation of a HTML document I have no clue how to change the attributes name.

Answer (score 3):

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jkedsp) You can do it with hostlistener and directive create one directive

```
import { Directive, HostListener, ElementRef, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[changes]'
})
export class HoverClassDirective {

  constructor(public elementRef:ElementRef) { }
  @Input('changes') changes:any;  

  @HostListener('mouseenter') onMouseEnter() {
    console.log()
    this.elementRef.nativeElement.title=this.changes;
 }

  @HostListener('mouseleave') onMouseLeave() {
    this.elementRef.nativeElement.title=this.changes;
  }

}
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vabbm4)  second way is css  you can put below code to sytle.css to also effect dynamically added

```
span {
  position: relative; 
}
span::after{
  position: absolute;
  display: none;  
}
span::after {
  content: attr(changes);  
  top: -20;
  left: -5px;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 4px;  
  padding: 2px 6px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  color: black;
  border: 1px solid gray
}
span:hover::after {
  display: block;  
}
```

Comment: Hmm... this works ONLY if I have only one element. As soon as I have multiple elements the approach fails - what a pity https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6focgz  Also the q arise does this work if the content is set by the DomSanitizer?

Comment: Yeah I see its working with your sample. Nevertheless I have two remarks: in the `app.component` you have `@Component` AND `@Directive` which I guess is a typo. I have updated my sample as well to meet my initial requirement. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-r1jsma. Unfortunately I have no clue how to initialize the Directive more properly. Any ideas?

Comment: try second way i added answer  @LeO

Comment: In principal this works although I have some troubles with the CSS. One issue with my code is that I need to apply `::ng-deep` which isn't my #1 preferred solution. Also I need to change little bit the content - which I thought I can do in one step. Anyway - I upvoted your response - and looking forward for a solution which allows some manipulation. Thx anyway.